# Why doesn't hasNextInt() method work for large integers?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a simple program which receives integer inputs from a Scanner object, determines whether it's a palindrome or not, and returns the boolean value.

For most numbers, it works well. However, at this code snippet:

```
private static void programRunner() {
    System.out.print("Insert your number:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (in.hasNextInt()) {
        int testNumber = in.nextInt();
        boolean result = palindromeTester(testNumber);
        System.out.println(result);
        programRunner();
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I added the "System.exit(0)" expression to make users easily terminate the program by intentionally typing any non-integer value. The problem is that when "considerably large" integers, such as "1234567654321," are provided, the code launches System.exit(0) which means it's not recognized as an integer?

I believe it's the problem lies in the "default radii" of the hasNextInt method, which probably limits the size of integer values it recognizes. (The program runs fine up to 9-digit integers) But I'm not sure. Or is there something wrong with the recursion?

Comment: 1) That's not an int but rather looks to be in the range of a long. 2) Why even get ints when you're not using the data in a numerical way? Get the data as a String instead.

Comment: use `hasNextLong()` and `nextLong()` as you've exceeded the range limit for `int` types.

Comment: That said, using recursion like that is inefficient, use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: On a side note, the *radix* has nothing to do with the size of an `int`, but tells the `Scanner` which *radix* (*base*) the alphanumeric integer representation is using. Usually you have `base10`, which is `0-9`, but you could also have `base2` (binary) or `base16` (hexadecimal), or any other base. The maximum value an `int` can hold always remains the same either way. See [wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yup, using the String data type will be much easier and simpler. I stuck to using such method only because the practice question prohibited the use of integer to string transformation. :P Thanks though

Comment: You don't need to convert to a number type to determine if a string is palindromic. So the string to int restriction is likely a hint for you. Take sting in and work with the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because an `int` in Java is **32 bit** and can only hold `2^31 - 1` (2147483647) as maximum value (see also [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)).

Anything bigger than that is not `int`, but `long` (except if it's even bigger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, in which case you need to get the value as `BigInteger`.)

See [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), [Long.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE), 
[Scanner.nextInteger()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInteger()), [Scanner.nextLong()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong()), 
[Scanner.nextBigInteger()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBigInteger()) and [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Forgot the basics of JAVA. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextLong()` if you have larg "`long`" integers to read like so :

```
private static void programRunner() {

        System.out.print("Insert your number:");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (in.hasNextLong())
        {
            long testNumber = in.nextLong();
            boolean result = palindromeTester(testNumber);
            System.out.println(result);
            programRunner();
        }
        else
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        }
```

Comment: `int testNumber = in.nextLong();` You might wanna make that a long ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've exceeded the range limit for the `int` type. the `long` type seems like what you're looking for.

So, you can either use the `hasNextLong()` and `nextLong()` methods of the `Scanner` class or as  @Hovercraft Full Of Eels has suggested in the comments since you're not using the data in a numerical way, it may be better to receive the data as a `String` instead.

Lastly, but not least I find it inefficient to use recursion here as each recursive call creates a new stack frame along with that for each recursive invocation you're newing up a `Scanner` instance. it's better to use a `while` loop instead.